# overriding value .... in class ..... of type Solution; value ..... has incompatible type (scala)

Tags: scala, abstract-class

Can someone help me?

```
abstract class Puzzle {

  val sections : List[Int]

  val valid : (Position => Boolean)

  val initSoln  : Solution

  val initDir : Direction 

}

case class StandardPuzzle() extends Puzzle { 

  val sections = snake

  val valid = inCube(3)_

  val initSoln = List(List(1,1,1))

  val initDir = (0,0,1)

}
```

after using Scala interpreter :

```
<console>:22: error: overriding value initSoln in class Puzzle of type Solution;
 value initSoln has incompatible type

val initSoln = List(List(1,1,1))
```

What is to do to solve this problem??

Thank you very much :))

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to override a method that should return `Solution` with a method that returns `List[List[Int]]`. So you can either change `initSoln` signature in `Puzzle` to return `List[List[Int]]` or return an instance of `Solution` in `StandardPuzzle`. But we can't help with that if you don't provide us with definition of `Solution` class.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, I think you only need to change the vals in your abstract class to defs at which point the vals defined in the case class will override the defs in the abstract class...

```
abstract class Puzzle {

  def sections : List[Int]

  def valid : (Position => Boolean)

  def initSoln : Solution

  def initDir : Direction 

}
```

However, I would also advise that you re-write your `case class` to accept parameters in a constructor rather than hard coding them...

```
case class StandardPuzzle() extends Puzzle { 

  val sections = snake

  val valid = inCube(3)_

  val initSoln = List(List(1,1,1))

  val initDir = (0,0,1)

}
```

...becomes...

```
case class StandardPuzzle(sections: List[Int], valid : (Position => Boolean), initSoln: Solution, initDir : Direction) extends Puzzle
```

...and then create an instance of `StandardPuzzle` as follows...

```
val puzzle = StandardPuzzle(snake, inCube(3)_, List(List(1,1,1)), (0,0,1))
```

Hopefully that will work, if not you need to provide more details on the problem, in particular, we need to know the definition of the `Solution` type.